.NET Core migration - migrating Newtonsoft to System.Text.Json
I'm migrating an API from .NET Standard to .NET Core 6, and want to have both API working alongside (to be backward compatible).
Therefore I need to use both Newtonsoft and System.Text.Json in order to apply JSON attributes like JsonIgnore, camel case, etc.
If I use Newtonsoft attributes and run the .NET Core API, it ignores these attributes.
If I use System.Text.Json and run the .NET Standard API, it ignores these attributes.
How should I handle this?

Both Newtonsoft and System.Text.Json are compatible with both .Net standard and .Net 6, so why do you need to use both?

Please post a [mre]. I've seen Newtonsoft and STJ work alongside just fine. All you need to do is be vary of naming duplicates and make things explicit, where need be. (Ignoring the question if you actually need to use both for now)

Do you mean you will have a model which contains both two packages's attribute? Then you want to let the attribute only work when running at specific environment?

How should I handle this? -- you can just apply both attributes using their fully qualified names.  Does that answer your question?  If not, can you explain a little more where you are stuck?  Thanks!

I tried to use both attributes on the same property and it works fine..
basically the issue was if I apply only system.text.json attribute and then make a request from my .net framework API, the attribute wasnt applied (but it applied successfully when making a request from the .NetCore ) and same with the othe package

Have you checked MS guide for migrating newtonsoft to system.text.json? There are some things compatible and some not which might be solved with workarounds as detailed in the link  MS guide

Table of differences
The following table lists Newtonsoft.Json features and System.Text.Json equivalents. The equivalents fall into the following categories:


System.text.json https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/overview
The library is built-in as part of the shared framework for .NET Core 3.0 and later versions. The source generation feature is built-in as part of the shared framework for .NET 6 and later versions.
For framework versions earlier than .NET Core 3.0, install the System.Text.Json NuGet package. The package supports:
.NET Standard 2.0 and later
.NET Framework 4.6.2 and later
.NET Core 2.1 and later
.NET 5 and later

yes, I checked the docs.. but when pointing the dotnetframework api and try to use the text.json attributes it doesnt work for me.. (like it's not applying) but on the dotnet core api it does..

Is framework version compatible? system.text.json The library is built-in as part of the shared framework for .NET Core 3.0 and later versions. The source generation feature is built-in as part of the shared framework for .NET 6 and later versions.
For framework versions earlier than .NET Core 3.0, install the System.Text.Json NuGet package. The package supports:
.NET Standard 2.0 and later
.NET Framework 4.6.2 and later
.NET Core 2.1 and later
.NET 5 and later
